# WMI Providers with ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, reporting-services, wmi

I'm writing a small ASP.NET page to detect and display information for installed SSRS instances on the local server.

I found the following tool really useful from Microsoft... [WMI Code Creator](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=2cc30a64-ea15-4661-8da4-55bbc145c30e&displaylang=en)

The code it generates works great when run from the command line. However when trying to execute the same code within my ASP.NET page I get a...

*"Unhandled Execution Error" 
Exception Details: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException*

This is the code...

```
    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\Microsoft\\SqlServer\\ReportServer\\[INSTANCE_HERE]\\v10\\Admin", "SELECT * FROM MSReportServer_ConfigurationSetting");

    foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
    {
        Response.Write(string.Format("InstanceName: {0}", queryObj["InstanceName"]));
    }
```

My guess is there is some sort of permissions issue via IIS, however I'd be grateful for a definitive answer. I thought it might be a problem with all WMI providers through ASP.NET, however the following code works fine in the page...

```
ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("root\\CIMV2", "SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem");

    foreach (ManagementObject queryObj in searcher.Get())
    {
        Response.Write(string.Format("Name: {0}", queryObj["Name"]));
    }
```

Any help as to what exactly is going on behind the scenes and maybe why I'm getting the above exception would be very welcome.

Comment: did you try giving dcom permissions to network services, if you need more help how to do it let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add Network Service account into the launch conditions for DCOM using dcomcnfg.

Type dcomcnfg in cmd

go to Component Services ->My Computer ->Com Security ->Lauch and Activate Permissions ->Edit Default ->Add...

Now add Network Service and allow all permisions to it.

Comment: To get to 'Com Security' (it's a tab) you need to look at the 'Properties' of 'My Computer'.